# How to style SVGs using CSS?

Tags: css, svg

I need to change the color of an SVG. How do we style the SVG using CSS?

I have 1 SVG, I'm trying to have 2 SVGS with different colors.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

We can use special css for svg here.  For example we have a two svg:

On first svg we will add a class for example 'red' and 'blue' on the other one.

Then set a style for those classes like

```
.red {
 fill: red ;
}

.blue {
 fill: blue ;
}
```